# Non linear regression using neural networks: Curve not fitting at some points

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, regression

My model has 2 independent variables and one dependent variable.

I am using a neural network 5 layer neural network to fit my curve, and I am using Keras for the purpose.

After 2000 epochs, I am getting a mean squared error of **500**. I want to bring it down, I've tried everything: different optimizers, learning rates, architectures, and nothing works.

**The main problem is that for most of the curve, it fits exactly, but at the end of the curve, it does not fit properly. I do not know how to correct this.**

In the figure below, the blue curve is the actual curve, and the red curve is the predicted curve for the test data.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the number of hidden units in each layer? Have you tried increasing the number of layers? Have you tried different activation functions?

Comment: Yes, as I've said, I've tried everything.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet? With a sufficiently large network, you should be able to fit the curve precisely, you might have a bug somewhere.

Comment: Are you clipping your training or test data anywhere?